# nodejs robinhood api login

Tags: api, authentication, token

I am trying to login to the robinhood API, I turned 2fa and sms off in the app but am still getting an error does this look correct below or is robinhood just slow at updating when 2fa is turned off.

```
   var credentials = {
        username: '*****',
        password: '*****'
    };
    var Robinhood = require('robinhood')(credentials, function(){
        console.log(Robinhood.auth_token());
            //      <authenticated alphanumeric token>
    })
```

the error

```
Error: token not found {"statusCode":400,"body":{"detail":"Request blocked, challenge type required.","accept_challenge_types":{"sms":"SMS"}},"headers":{"date":"Mon, 24 May 2021 22:44:07 GMT","content-type":"application/json","content-length":"93","connection":"close","server":"openresty","allow":"POST, OPTIONS","x-robinhood-api-version":"0.0.0","content-security-policy":"default-src 'none'","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","access-control-allow-origin":"https://robinhood.com","vary":"Origin","trace-uuid":"56ccb9cc-8bca-4dbd-be6f-4a6d86171354"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"api.robinhood.com","port":443,"hostname":"api.robinhood.com","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/oauth2/token/","path":"/oauth2/token/","href":"https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Host":"api.robinhood.com","Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Referer":"https://robinhood.com/","Origin":"https://robinhood.com","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","content-length":214}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robinhood recently required 2fa to be enabeld if using the api. It is mentioned in the detail of the request body.

```
"detail":"Request blocked, challenge type required.","accept_challenge_types":{"sms":"SMS"}}
```

Go ahead and turn it on and then you can access the api with this snippet

```
let Robinhood = require('robinhood')(credentials, function(data) {
    if (data && data.mfa_required) {
        var mfa_code = ""; //Notice this is blank. 
        Robinhood.set_mfa_code(mfa_code, () => {
            console.log(Robinhood.auth_token());
            Robinhood.positions((error, response, body) => {
                console.log(body);
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Once you make a request you'll get an error, but the 2fa challenge will be sent to whatever you set your account with. Once you received the 2fa code, set the mfa_code and re-run the snippet. Once you ran the snippet again with a valid 2fa code, then you've successfully logged in. Copy the authorization token and you can use that without the need of going through 2fa again for i believe 24 hrs